# Firebase web application - Calling gotData function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building a web app with JS and firebase as my DB, but I'm struggeling to call on my gotData function to get it's return value.

```
var dbRef = firebase.database().ref('testing');

function reading(){
      dbRef.on('value', gotData,errData) ;
      }

function gotData(data){

  var tests = data.val();
  var keys = Object.keys(tests);
  var length = keys.length;
  var k = keys[lengthe-1];
  console.log(k)
  console.log(data)
  return k;
}

function errData(err){
  alert('error')
}
```

The code works and I get the documentID of the newest document returned, but I fail to call on this value.

I tried:

```
var fbid = gotData(data);
```

but I get an *data is not defined* error. From my understanding data is just used to reference to the Firebase data so I can do operations on it. What do I need to do, so that I can call the function with it's data ?

Comment: That sounds unusual indeed, as the snapshot should always exist in the callback. I don't immediatly see what's wrong in the code you posted. Can you set up a small reproduction on a site like jsbin, so that I can have a look?

Comment: Here is the jsbin: https://jsbin.com/jenahuh/edit?html,output . This part of code is only to test, once it works I'll implement it into my website. The sole purpose of this function is to get the ID of the newest document in my Firebase(var k in my code) and then use it in another function. Thanks for looking into this :)

Comment: That's unfortunately not very helpful, as it doesn't actually reproduce the problem. If you're afraid of sharing your project configuration (which [is not needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public), but still quite common), you can create a temporary project for the jsbin, and then delete that project afterwards.

Comment: Okay, I will delete it once the problem is solved. This is the whole project, so I hope this helps to find a solution: https://jsbin.com/mewojen/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `gotData()` yourself at the bottom of the code in the jsbin, without passing in a parameter:

```
var id = gotData();
```

How I found this:

1. Put this line as the first statements inside `gotData()`:

   ```
   if (!data) debugger
   ```
2. Run the code in the jsbin again, which starts the debugger now.
3. Check the call stack (on the right hand side in the Chrome debugger) to see where the call came from.

You'll want to remove this `gotData()` call, and put all code that needs the data *inside* the `gotData()` functions. Also see:

- [Passing variable in parent scope to callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26297654/passing-variable-in-parent-scope-to-callback-function/26299662#26299662)
- [Firebase Query inside function returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28381006/firebase-query-inside-function-returns-null/28382922#28382922)
- [Why Does Firebase Lose Reference outside the once() Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40688268/why-does-firebase-lose-reference-outside-the-once-function/40688890#40688890)
- [Is there any way to break Javascript function within an anonymous function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31054852/is-there-any-way-to-break-javascript-function-within-an-anonymous-function/31056003#31056003)

Comment: Okay, thanks. I thought there would be a way to call on the function, putting all the code that needs the data was my backup plan if nothing else works. Thanks for your help. Can I do something else besides giving you an upvote(this is my first post on stack overflow)?

Comment: Alright, I will read through the links later this evening. I wrote everything inside the gotData and it works like intended. Thanks for the help :)